# REST - how to handle needless requests?

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, spring-mvc

I playing with my simple REST API prototype written in Spring 3.2 MVC / Tomcat 7.4 / PostgreSQL.

Now I am thinking what is the best way to solve these issues:

1. Somebody make a request to a resources that doesn't exist
2. Somebody make a request to a resource but is using unsupported HTTP method
3. Somebody make a request to a resource but provide incorrect or incomplete data

Issue 3 I can probably solve with checking data and response proper HTTP headers (HTTP 400 or HTTP 404 because data could not be found because some input data is missing), but I don't know how to solve (in Spring) issue 1 and 2.

What is the best practice for handling exceptions such these?

Answer (score 1):

**For issue 1** just return a 404 error.

Create a 404 exception:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

}
```

Now throw that from any handler and the client will get a 404 error.

**For issue 2** the framework will automatically generate and return an error page for you if you set up your filters correctly, or if not generate and send a 405 not allowed code.

**For issue 3** return a 400 Bad Syntax error in the same way as for issue 1 - or generate a more complex error return detailing the problem.

Comment: Thanks, How to solve catching these exceptions it programatically in Spring? Is there some way how to catch it via some global trycatch class?

Comment: You don't catch them, you throw them. If they request something that isn't present throw the ResourceNotFoundException. Spring will detect that, read the annotation, and generate an appropriate 404 error and page.

Comment: Yes, I understand you. Do you think that I am not responsible to catch the exceptions throwed from my API and make the Tomcat to solve it itself?

Answer (score 1):

1. Return 404 (Not found)
2. Return 405 (Method not allowed)
3. Return 400 (Bad Request)

A word of advice, the body/headers of 404 that you return when someone request a URL path that doesn't exist should be different than if a resource doesn't exist. This will allow your clients to figure out if they are calling the wrong url or if the resource doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

- For the case #1, it's a clear 404 Not Found.
- For the case #2, it's 405 Method Not Allowed.
- For the case #3, it's a 400 Bad Request.

See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html for the description of these cases and the reasoning behind it.